# Lifting automorphisms of quotient groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

I am concerning here a natural question:

> **Problem:** Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $N$ be a characteristic subgroup of $G$. When can an automorphism $\varphi\in\mathrm{Aut}(G/N)$ be lifted to an automorphism of $G$?

The problem in general seems difficult, and it has raised four years before in MathOverflow ([see this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103368/automorphisms-of-quotient-groups)).

**Question:** for which classes (or cases) of groups $G$ or $N$ has this Problem been studied?

Comment: Consider the case that $N = \Phi(G)$ in which case $G/N$ has large automorphism group. There are many cases though when ${\rm Aut}(G)$ is a $p$-group.

Comment: The question as stated doesn't seem to admit a unique correct answer. A better, more focused, question, would ask whether the question has been studied in a particular instance.

Comment: The question also seems to have changed. My comment above concerned the case $N$ a p-group.